# Barcodes in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, barcode

can anyone suggest me a barcode font /module to use with access 2010/2007 which can generate 128 barcodes?
I would be really thankful if anyone could help me.

Comment: http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm

Answer (score 3):

I dunno much bout barcodes but i used this one in d past, if it might be helpfull to you:

Font FRE3OF9X

google it, u can download it free from any site

edit:

there u go, 
http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/